# Problems getting a jQuery .mouseenter()/.mouseleave() script with user interaction to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, mouseleave, mouseenter

Firstly, apologies for the title, I could not think of a suitable one.

I am unsure as to why the hide() function within the below code comes back erroneous in firebug when triggered, I am pretty sure the rest of the code will work fine once I have ironed this flaw out, any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Firebug Console error:

```
hide is not defined
it-services() it-services (line 396)
time = setTimeout("hide()",3000);
```

Code I have thus far:

```
        var time;

        $("#form").mouseenter(function() {
            clearTimeout(time);
            $(this).delay(800).animate({
                right: 0
            }, 2000);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            function hide() {
                $(this).delay(800).animate({
                    right: "-325px"
                }, 1000);
            }
            time = setTimeout(hide,3000);
        });
```

Thank you all very much for any help in advance,

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the `hide()` function after you invoke it using `setTimeout`. Simply put the declaration before the `setTimeout` call.

Also, when you pass a string of code as first argument to `setTimeout`, it gets `eval`ed. `eval` is evil. Just pass the function object:

```
function hide() {
    $(this).delay(800).animate({
        right: "-325px"
    }, 1000);
}
time = setTimeout(hide, 3000);
```

Comment: Have edited my original code to show your code, but still the code doesnt not work, and I get a new error. """elem.ownerDocument is undefined
if ( !(defaultView = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView) ) {}

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in the new code

1. Inside the hide function, the context of $(this) is not same as the
   when it is being called inside the mouseout function.
2. Secondly, the hide function is defined as an anonymous function inside the mouseout function

I feel it would make more sense if it were a function declared outside the mouseover event handling function. That way you can globally reference it from the setTimeOut as well as the mouseout event handler. Try the below code. I believe this should solve the issue, or at least take you a step ahead.

```
var time;
var $form;

$("#form").mouseenter(function() {
    $form = $(this);
    clearTimeout(time);
    $(this).delay(800).animate({
        right: 0
    }, 2000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    hide();
    time = setTimeout(hide,1000);
});
function hide() {
    $form.delay(800).animate({
        right: "-325px"
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Good comment, certainly does make sense putting the hide() outside the scope of the .mouseleave()